# How to acknowledge in-app purchases in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-iap

here is my code

```
const purchase = {
  "purchaseToken": "fjjijcpgpadpaafpihlmlbpf.AO-J1OzNNbilg8roTwAQs-GNqMiEHWx8bcloXZs5md9u_sSekWfvhWY24DKy4yI1UegLVyEA6NmljaClMYqU2iJSDEFYMFV5og"
};

if(purchase && purchase.purchaseToken){
  RNIap.acknowledgePurchaseAndroid(purchase.purchaseToken);
}else{
  console.log("Invalid Purchase Object or Purchase Token");
}
```

I getting error as follows:

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
> kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter token

Answer (score 0):

`acknowledgePurchaseAndroid();` is expecting an object not a string.

Replace with `acknowledgePurchaseAndroid({token: purchase.purchaseToken});`